# Prepend api to root of URL in Play Framework

Tags: java, api, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm creating an api using Play Framework, and I'd like to use the standard url for an api - api.mysite.com.

But I can't seem to find a way to prepend api to the URL. It seems play framework only supports urls like msite.com/api.

Is that correct or is there another way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general Play 2.0 does not support multidomain routes, so you have such scenarios possible:

1. Build two separate apps for `API` and for `frontend` and use some HTTP server as a reverse proxy.
2. Build one application, you can call it with both: `domain.tld` and `api.domain.tld` however for api calls you need to add additional routes like `api.domain.tld/api` in such case you can also compare in your controller if for an example request for url `/api/get-item/123.json` is done in right domain and return `badRequest()` or `redirect()` if it isn't.